# caching with no notification and no polling, is there another way around it

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, t-sql, caching

i know about query notifications, but they're so limited because of lack of support for aggregation functions. so if i forget the SqlDependancy what other options do i have for OUTPUT caching in ASP.NET website? is there a way to call an outside code from inside of SQL Server?(2005 and above). like calling a webservice from a trigger?

it is important to say that my data is not changed so regularly which makes the polling technique so "not right for the job". the reason for that is because of me having a shopping website which  needs the data to be fresh, so anytime a change has been made it has to be shown to the user immediately. that is why i'm looking for a similar technique to query notification but without its limitations.

Comment: Does the ASP.NET application need to know about a change immediately? Instead of caching within ASP.NET would you consider caching the data within, say, a local copy of SQL Express that is kept relatively (near real-time) up to date from the original source?

Comment: http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html

Comment: @AaronBertrand but wouldn't that still hits the database engine? isn't caching is almost about saving that round trip?

Comment: @jim if it's a separate instance of SQL Server, and especially if they're different physical servers, then (a) your reads are no longer interfering with, or being interfered with by, the read/write activity on the primary copy of the data, and (b) you take network traffic out of the equation entirely, and can use shared memory locally, which may be faster depending on other factors.

Comment: i can't do that because i don't have full access to website host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert a service broker message from a trigger. Your application can listen on that particular message queue. That allows you do build arbitrary notification logic, including aggregation.

`SqlDependency` uses service broker internally, but with less flexibility.

Comment: since you brought this up, why SqlDependancy is skipping a good part of service broker?(aggregations)

Comment: Because query notifications don't support them. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130764.aspx)

Comment: i'm using LINQ, is that a problem?

Comment: Why would it? Maybe you should ask a new question to get more details on that.

Comment: can you give me a link that actually implements a service broker messaging to an application instead of another db or db server? because i couldn't find any! specially for asp.net+sb

Comment: Your app needs to execute a RECEIVE statement http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186963.aspx I found the Service Broker docs to be useful.